# Restricting tables for the package "laravel-ask-database"

Tags: php, laravel, openai-api

I'm new to the world of laravel development I came across a package to generate natural queries for the database called "laravel-ask-database", is there a way I can restrict which tables this package has access to?

Answer (score 1):

The [laravel-ask-database](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-ask-database) is getting the all table list from db schema [line 34](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-ask-database/blob/eae5785d5b41f04d03dcf8d919762cb7766aad82/src/Oracle.php#L34):

```php
protected function getTables(string $question): array
    {
        return once(function () use ($question) {
            $tables = DB::connection($this->connection)
                ->getDoctrineSchemaManager()
                ->listTables();

            if (count($tables) < config('ask-database.max_tables_before_performing_lookup')) {
                return $tables;
            }

            return $this->filterMatchingTables($question, $tables);
        });
    }
```

And there is no configurable filter. However, as an option to protect tables, you can create an additional MySQL user named `laravel-ask-database` with custom-specific table privileges.

To add the custom `laravel-ask-database` connection to config/database.php, use the following configuration:

```php
'connections' => [
...
        'laravel-ask-database' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => 'laravel-ask-database',
            'password' => ...,
            ...
        ],
...
]
```

next change the default value of `ask-database.connection` (config/ask-database.php) via `.env` file:

```
ASK_DATABASE_DB_CONNECTION=laravel-ask-database
```

This will not protect the construction of SQL queries for restricted tables, but it will protect access to them.

Alternative ways:

- Fork the project or make a pull request.
- Avoid using restricted table names in prompts.

hope this helps you